# PromQL: Counting samples of a time series

Tags: count, counting, promql, scalar

For a 2 minute time window this vector has the following results (I am using Grafana Explore with a picked 2 minute time):

```
instana_metrics{aggregation="max", endpoint="mutation addProduct"}

t1 - 3051
t2 - 5347
t3 - 5347
t4 - 4224
t5 - 4224
```

I need something equivalent to

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   instana_metrics
```

with a result of **5**.

The best I was able to come up with is this

```
count( instana_metrics{aggregation="max", endpoint="mutation addProduct"} )

t1 | 1
t2 | 1
t3 | 1
t4 | 1
t5 | 1
```

My interpretation is that every point in time has a count of 1 sample value. But the result itself is a time series, and I am expecting one scalar.

Btw: I understand that I can use Grafana transformation for this, but unfortunately I need a PromQL only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [count_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_over_time) function. For example, the following query returns the number of raw samples over the last 2 minutes per each time series with the name `instana_metrics`:

```
count_over_time(instana_metrics[2m])
```

Note that Prometheus calculates the provided query independently per each point on the graph, e.g. each value on the graph shows the number of raw samples per each matching time series  over 2 minutes lookbehind window ending at the given point.

If you need just a single value per each matching series over the selected time range in Grafana, then use the following instant query:

```
count_over_time(instana_metrics[$__range])
```

See [these docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/global-variables/#__range) about `$__range` variable.

See [these docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/) about instant query type in Grafana.